What is the most common CMOS failure mode in the wild?
When repairing electronic devices, I tend to see a significant bias toward modern CMOS ICs failing shorted to ground. In fact, I don't think I have ever seen a digital CMOS device that failed shorted to Vdd. That got me thinking. I should want to take this into consideration if I was engineering a device for high reliability.
Is that actually a reliable observation to use when designing, or have I just seen an anomaly that doesn't represent the norm?
What's the actual official word on CMOS failure mode statistics? Is there even one?

Note: I am aware that much research has been done on general reliability (e.g. MTBF, HTOL). This question is not asking about the probability of a failure happening, it's asking about the result of failure that will occur when it eventually does happen. In such a scenario failure is a certainty, the outcome is the variable under test.

Are you talking about inputs, outputs or Vdd?  Vdd to GND short is possible, which could rapidly turn into open and probably various pins shorted to GND.

How are you measuring the short? If you measure it in-circuit, be aware that Vdd to GND in a complex PWB may be 10-50 ohms. A simple ohmmeter test on an I/O pin may indicate low impedance to both GND and Vdd.

When I am inspecting a circuit, my default is to attach the negative lead of my DMM to a solid ground and leave it there 99% of the time. Doing this finds the most faults the quickest in my experience. Going with this, "shorted to ground" means an IC pin has low impedance (<10 Ohms) between itself and ground as shown between my positive probe (on the pin under test) and negative probe (on the ground plane). As far as inputs, outputs, or Vdd, it's all of the above. When I find a faulty IC, it's almost always faulty as a pin (any of the above) shorted to ground where it really should not be.
